# Using vim on Windows to parse a .sql file

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, vim

My Generate Scripts SQL file including my CREATE commands for various views and tables is too large for a regular notepad editor.  I am using `vim`.  However, every character has a `^@` between it.  So `CREATE TABLE` looks like this:

```
^@C^@R^@E^@A^@T^@E^@ ^@T^@A^@B^@L^@E
```

Is this normal?  Basically, there are only a few `CREATE` scripts I really want in this file.  Particularly, I am looking for any line that has `[dbo].[v_agent` in it.  I understand `grep` commands, but I am sitting waiting for the command to run and want to know if I am wasting my time or not.

Comment: How did you generate the script? There is a ScriptingOptions… option to set the encoding for the output (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.encoding.aspx), but I'm not seeing it exposed in the SSMS options. My suspicion is that the file is UTF-16 and vim is expecting (or interpreting) UTF-8.

Comment: I used Tasks -> Generate Scripts

Comment: I did a little bit of research and it seems like this is a long-standing request to MS (to at least give users the option to choose a different encoding). You could try your hand at a powershell script in which you could set the ScriptingOptions.Encoding to UTF-8. Otherwise, I like the vim tip provided below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern MS Windows programs and utilities (such as SQL Server) create text files using the UTF-16 LE (little end) character encoding.

By default, Unix utilities such as `grep` don’t interpret such files as being text files and instead treat them as binary files (streams of bytes).

---

If you’re running a Unix emulator (e.g., Cygwin), the `iconv` tool could be
used to convert this to a different encoding such as UTF-8, e.g.

```
iconv -f utf16le -t utf8 in.sql > out.sql
```

---

Since you’ve already stated that you have the file open in Vim, you can re-open it using this Vim command:

```
:set encoding=utf8
:e ++encoding=utf16le
```

The first command is used to make sure that Unicode characters can be
represented correctly when the file is loaded into a Vim buffer. It should not be necessary as the default encoding is usually set to UTF-8.

Vim doesn’t automatically recognise the file as being encoded in UTF-16LE so the second command re-opens the file for editing; you have to tell it which character encoding that should be used to interpret the stream of bytes that make up the file.  For more info, see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reloading_a_file_using_a_different_encoding

Now that the file is loaded correctly into a Vim buffer, you could set the `fileencoding` option to any character encoding that you would like to save the file with.